# Why work done by friction is positive?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, friction

Imagine a chain of mass m hanging from a table(not frictionless) which slips down the table. I want to calculate work done by friction. Obviously as it opposes slipping it should be negative. However while i solved it using integration my answer is positive. What am i missing?
[image: My approach.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two things together.

The work computed by the integral $W=\int \vec{F}_f \cdot d\vec{x}$ is really an integral along some path. The dot product $\vec{F}_f \cdot d\vec{x}$ simply tells you "take the component of the force in the direction of the path and integrate along the path from initial point to final point as the distance rises". Now, if you take for simplicity just the endpoint of the chain, this endpoint moves from position $x=l/4$ to position $x=0$. The path integral bounds are however not from initial position to final position, but from initial distance traveled to end distance traveled. This makes sense, since in the case of constant force the work is indeed force times the distance traveled and not force times difference in position. Difference in position is of course negative, as the position is decreasing from $l/4$ to $0$, but the distance is positive and it grows from $0$ to $l/4$.

The problem is, you are calling both, the position and the distance along the path $x$, even though they go in opposite direction.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that blatantly go against site policy

Comment: @BioPhysicist  what policy? Also, did you just downvoted for this sole reason?

Comment: Check my work questions are off topic

Comment: This answer helps though. Accepted. My doubt was addressed and resolved. How was it against the group policy? You downvoted my question too. @BioPysicist

Comment: @BioPhysicist It is not off topic and check my work type. It address my misconception of the concept of relating work by a force to position instead of distance. Please retract ur actions.

Comment: @madhubalasingh "*Please see my approach in the image below and point out where i went wrong.*"

Comment: @BioPhysicist Please do not comment anything irrelevant to the Question (like you have). I don't see any harm this question does to you/anyone else. If it doesn't interest you,why not just move on?

Comment: @user600016 All of my comments have been about this question/answer actually. Also, I never said anything about this question not interesting me. It's about the site policies; nothing personal at all here.

Comment: @BioPhysicist This is not "check my work" question though. The questions is "help me to spot my mistake", with good description of why the solution is wrong. I could not find anything on meta marking this as off topic, and I do think such questions have place here as the mistake might lead to an interesting answer, helping more people to clear some confusions or avoid doing the same mistake. And as the mistake is mysterious at the time of writing the question, it cannot be asked in any better way

Comment: @BioPhysicist not saying the question is not downvote-worthy though...Just I do not think it is off-topic here

Comment: That is fine. You are entitled to have your opinion. Many other users disagree (which is why the question was closed). "help me spot my mistake" is exactly the same thing as "check my work". They are asking you to look at the work, and check what is wrong. When I see someone posting their work and asking others to point out what is wrong, to me that is clearly a check-my-work question, which is definitely off topic.

Comment: If you think there is nothing on meta addressing this, then please ask a question on meta. It will certainly be helpful for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Limits taken are wrong. Since you have already taken cos180, you must take limits 0 to l/4, not the opposite. Then you'll get work done as negative

Comment: But why. Limits are values of range of x. As x changes from l/4 to 0 the limits should also be that same l/4 to 0.

Comment: Initially, you have already assumed friction to be opposite to your direction of motion. If you had not assumed so, and taken cos0 instead, taking value of limits as l/4 to 0 would have been valid. You can think of the point at the edge of the table as the origin.

Comment: I do not understand "assumed friction to be in opposite direction". It is actuallly in opposite direction. How does assuming correct direction for the force invert the work done by it? Or are you suggesting that x ranges from -l/4 to 0 considering origin to be at the edge of the table? Does that mean any other choice of origin might give different results?

Comment: Please don't answer questions that blatantly go against site policy